# C is integer math equivalent with unsigned math?

Tags: c, math, unsigned

So can i cast the values to unsigned values, do the operation and cast back, and get the same result? I want to do this because unsigned integers can overflow, while signed cant.

Comment: In short, sometimes.

Comment: If the result overflows, no casting will get round it. If an intermediate part of the computation can overflow, cast to a larger type and then back, for example `int` to `long long`, and `unsigned` to `unsigned long long`.

Comment: I dont want to prevent overflows, i want to have overflows which dont crash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unsigned integer arithmetic does not *overflow* in C terminology because it is defined to wrap modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup>, where *N* is the number of bits in the unsigned type being operated on, per C 2018 6.2.5 9:

> … A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type.

For other types, if an overflow occurs, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, per 6.5 5:

> If an *exceptional condition* occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined. Note that not just the result is undefined; the entire behavior of the program is undefined. It could give a result you do not expect, it could trap, or it could execute entirely different code from what you expect.

Regarding your question:

> So can I cast the values to unsigned values, do the operation and cast back, and get the same result?

we have two problems. First, consider `a + b` given `int a, b;`.  If `a + b` overflows, then the behavior is not defined by the C standard. So we cannot say whether converting to `unsigned`, adding, and converting back to `int` will produce the same result because there is no defined result for `a + b` to start with.

Second, the conversion back is partly implementation-defined, per C 6.3.1.3. Consider `int c = (unsigned) a + (unsigned) b;`, which implicitly converts the `unsigned` sum to an `int` to store in `c`. Paragraph 1 tells us that, if the value of the sum is representable in `int`, it is the result of the conversion. But paragraph 3 tells us what happens if the value is not representable in `int`:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

GCC, for example, [defines the result to be the result of wrapping modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup>](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html). So, for `int c = (unsigned) a + (unsigned) b;`, GCC will produce the same result as `int c = a + b;` would if `a + b` wrapped modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup>. However, GCC does not guarantee the latter. When optimizing, GCC expects overflow will not occur, which can result in it eliminating any code branches where the program does allow overflow to occur. (GCC may have some options regarding its treatment of overflow.)

Additionally, even if both signed arithmetic and unsigned arithmetic wrap, performing an operation using unsigned values and converting back does not mathematically produce the same result as doing the operation with signed values. For example, consider `-3/2`. The `int` result is −1. But if `-3` is converted to 32-bit unsigned, the resulting value is 2<sup>32</sup>−3, and then `(int) ((unsigned) -3 / (unsigned) 2)` is 2<sup>−31</sup>−2 = 2,147,483,646.